# Discerning the correct position of adverbs

Tags: adverbs

...since life first appeared on earth.

...since first life appeared on earth.

...since life appeared on earth first.

Would anyone please readily explain the difference between these?

Or, could you possibly tell me how to distinguish where to put adverbs in such circumstances?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The canonical position for most adverbs is after the verb phrase, i.e. the verb and any object(s):

> Coco runs **fast**.
>
> Carla speaks Russian **fluently**. (Russian = object)
>
> He discredited the company and its CEO **intentionally**. (after verb and two objects)

However, there are adverbs that are more idiomatic -or- have a different meaning *in front of* the verb. In your example, **first** before the verb, means *initially*, whereas **first** after the verb phrase means *before another person or thing*.

> I **first** met Hank when he moved here from Texas. (=our initial meeting)
>
> I met Hank **first**, when he moved here from Texas. (=I was the first
> person to meet him -or- I met him before I met anyone else)

In another example, **quickly** has different meanings in these positions:

> I **quickly** switched the files in my bosses office. (= not wasting
> any time)
>
> I switched the files in my bosses office **quickly**. (= with rapid
> hand movements)

To answer your question, based on the above, sentences (1) and (3) are possible, however (2) isn't grammatical. To paraphrase them:

> (1) Ever since the moment when life **initially** appeared on Earth...
>
> (2) [*this is an outdated syntax for "first," but not ungrammatical*]
>
> (3) Given that life appeared on Earth **before any other place**...

Naturally, some adverbs can also occur at the beginning of the sentence or practically any position for that matter, e.g. **sometimes**, whereas others have syntactic strictures regarding their position and must be studied individually.

> **Sometimes** I just close my eyes and shut out the world.
>
> I **sometimes** just close my eyes and shut out the world.
>
> I close my eyes **sometimes** and just shut out the world.
>
> I just close my eyes and shut out the world **sometimes**.

Comment: I told her (2) isn't grammatical (which to me it isn't, although I may be wrong); and then paraphrased (1) and (3) for her, to show their distinct meanings.

Comment: As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since+first+we+met&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csince%20first%20we%20met%3B%2Cc0) suggests, we don't put ***first*** in that position so often these days. But it's certainly not in the least "ungrammatical" - just formal/dated/poetic, like I said. I hadn't noticed that point in your answer, but you're simply mistaken.

Comment: Got it! Changed.